# Remove only admin info in nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, datetime

I'm using Drupal 7 and Clean theme. And i want remove only submitted by admin, dont remove date info.

Looked node.tpl.php and node.module files but not seen this fields. How can i remove this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove $submitted from your template and use below code

`$timestamp = $node->created;
print format_date($timestamp, $type = 'medium', $format = '', $timezone = NULL, $langcode = NULL);`

Comment: Where i put this code? Which file? My template haven't $submitted

Comment: you can put this code in your node template.